# Automatic drag and drop when double clicking Angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-cdk

In my application, I have two lists of items that can be transferred from one to the other with the [DragDropModule](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api) from Angular Material.

I wish I could use the drag and drop, but also used the double click on one of the items of a list to transfer it to the other list automatically.

**Here is my code:** [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/automatic-drag-and-drop-when-double-clicking)

```
<div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    (dblclick)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
</div>
<div
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    (dblclick)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

But it does not work and I do not know how to do it, this is the first time I use drag and drop.
If anyone would have an idea to do that I would be interested.

**Here is the error displayed in the console when double clicking:**

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of `$event` for `cdkDropListDropped` and `dblclick` is different.
For `dblclick` `$event` is equal MouseEvent instance so there is no information about from where was item moved.

One solution came in my mind is just write a custom function that will take item name from dblclick event and get target and source names. With this information, you can easily move items between arrays directly.

In template, you need to use to move from todo to done `(dblclick)="dblclickMove($event.target.innerText, 'done', 'todo')"`
and vise versa for other block `(dblclick)="dblclickMove($event.target.innerText, 'todo', 'done')"`

On controller function like this:

```
  dblclickMove(itemName: string, ...targets: string[]) {
    this[targets[0]] = [
      ...this[targets[1]].splice(this[targets[1]].indexOf(itemName), 1), 
      ...this[targets[0]]
      ];
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/automatic-drag-and-drop-when-double-clicking-j93gqv)

Comment: Thank you very much I will test that.